# calculating NSString height to use in collectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create a collectionView with a single column (kind of tableview style) with cell of dynamic height. each cell will contain a top view which has a height of 50 points and has leading, trailing and top constraints to the cell. and the only other thing is some text below that, which will have dynamic height depending on its content. The issue is i tried to to use boundingRect method to calculate the size for the label but if the text is too long it will be cut off (clipped) and the cell is not as tall as it should. this is my code:

```
extension CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    let topViewHeight: CGFloat = 50
    let topAndBottomMargin: CGFloat = 8
    let width = collectionViewWidth - 4 * 2
    let text = answer[indexPath.item]

    let s = NSString(string: "hello")
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    let height = calculateTextHeight(for: text, font: font, width: width - 100)

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height + topViewHeight + topAndBottomMargin + 16)

}

func calculateTextHeight(for text: String, font:UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
    let estimateHeight = NSString(string: text).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: attributes, context: nil)
    let string = NSString(string: text)

    //let estimateHeight = string.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    print(estimateHeight.height)
    return CGFloat(ceil(estimateHeight.height))


}
```

second thing is i still do not understand is that how does the width in CGSize affect the overall height ?

i tried using NSString.size but that does not work at all. It gravely underestimates the height of the string

Comment: The text in the cell is in a UILabel? (did you set the max number of lines?)

Comment: i set it to 0 so it can have as much as it needs

Comment: The width quite obviously affects the height, because the width determines whether you have one, two, three or more lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

The LayoutManager will call the layout delegate to get the item size (the one you implemented), but it will do it only once and after keep this size in cache as a layoutAttribute (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes).

So maybe in your case it is using an old size (in cache) and your collection view has been resized in between?

So one of the thing to do, is to properly reset the layout cache when the collection view bound change (probably in viewWillAppear and willTransition?)
In this case do something like this:

```
 let context = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext()
 context.invalidateFlowLayoutAttributes = true
 context.invalidateFlowLayoutDelegateMetrics = true
 self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)
```

By doing this the layout will clear the cache and ask you for the correct width of your item with an up to date width. If you set each item to take max width, you will have one column

```
maxWidth = collectionView.bounds.width - layout.sectionInset.left - layout.sectionInset.right
```